# knockoutjs viewmodel structure - hint needed

Tags: knockout.js

i'm building an app whit knockout js and i have the message 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' when i click the 'edit' link to edit a single 'soggetto'.

two question:

- what's the error?
- is correct my viewmodel design?

this is my view model (here is slightly simplified)

```
var Soggetto= function(id,nome,citta){
    var self=this;
    self.id=ko.observable(id);
    self.nome=ko.observable(nome);
    self.citta=ko.observable(citta);
};

var Danneggiato=function(idSoggetto,danno,altro){
    var self=this;
    self.idSoggetto=ko.observable(idSoggetto);
    self.danno=ko.observable(danno);
    self.altro=ko.observable(altro);
};

var ViewModel = function(soggetti,idContraente,presenti,danneggiati){
    var self=this;
    self.soggetti=ko.observableArray(soggetti);
    self.contraente=ko.observable(idContraente);
    self.presenti=ko.observableArray(presenti);
    self.danneggiati=ko.observableArray(danneggiati);

    self.selectedItem= ko.observable();

    self.getSoggetto=function   (id){
       var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.soggetti(), function (item) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(id) == item.id();
        });
        if (match) {
            self.selectedItem(match);
            return match;
        }
        else
            return null;  
    };

};

var VM = new ViewModel([new Soggetto(1,'Pippo','Milano'),new Soggetto(2,'Pluto','Roma'),new Soggetto(3,'Paperino','Arnasco'),new Soggetto(4,'Paperoga','Genova')]
                       ,2
                       ,[3,1]
                       ,[new Danneggiato(4,250.00,''),new Danneggiato(2,153.50,'')]
                      );

ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

and this is the markup:

```
<div >
    <label>contraente: </label>
    <select data-bind="options: soggetti, value: contraente, optionsText: 'nome',optionsValue:'id'"></select>
    <br/>
    <label>presenti: </label>
   <ul data-bind="foreach: presenti">
                <li>
                    <span data-bind="text: $root.getSoggetto($data).nome"> </span>
                    <a data-bind="click:$root.getSoggetto($data)">edit</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
     <br/>
    <label>danneggiati: </label>
   <ul data-bind="foreach: danneggiati">
                <li>
                    <span data-bind="text: $root.getSoggetto(idSoggetto).nome"> </span>
                    <span data-bind="text: danno"> </span>
                    <a data-bind="click:$root.getSoggetto(idSoggetto)">edit</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
<div data-bind="with:selectedItem">
    <label>id: </label><span data-bind="text:id"></span>
    <br/>
    <label>nome: </label><input data-bind="value:nome"></input>
    <br/>
    <label>citta: </label><input data-bind="value:citta"></input>
</div>
```

this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcuyt2rw/14/)

Comment: I dont see any error on clicking the edit link. Can you provide the steps to recreate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you click binding is returning an object. You shouldn't return anything from the onclick. The simplest solution to fix the error is wrap the `getSoggetto` in another one which doesn't return:

```
self.getSoggettoClick = function (id) {
    self.getSoggetto(id);
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auj5qwco/)

As for the second question, I think the structure of the objects is a bit off. I would try to nest the objects as sub objects of each other, instead of using id to link them.

Comment: ok for the first, for the second you would do as you say, even if the 'Soggetto' object actually contains many more fields and the same Soggetto is linked many time in the model?

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you provide the structure in json as to how the objects link to each other. Do you have multiple Soggetto that have danneggiati and presenti or the other way round. Sorry I don't know Italian